# Procedure para criar banco de dados e suas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, procedure

Estou precisando criar um banco de dado para cada cliente que realiza um determinado cadastro, para isso criei uma `procedure` para fazer tal coisa.

Porém me deparei com um pequeno problema de identificação. Quando eu executo a `procedure` ela cria o banco de dados com o nome que eu passei por parâmetro, porém na hora de criar as tabelas, ela cria as tabelas no meu banco matriz onde a `procedure` foi criada, eu tentei usar o `USE nome_do_bando` para referenciar mas não deu certo. segue o código de exemplo:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `loja_virtual_dev`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `cria_banco_cliente`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`loja_virtual_dev`@`%` PROCEDURE `cria_banco_cliente`(IN var_banco VARCHAR(40))
main:BEGIN
    IF(var_banco <> '') THEN
        SELECT var_banco AS msg;
        SET @teste = CONCAT("CREATE DATABASE ",var_banco," DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1");
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @teste;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

        -- USE `var_banco`$$

        SET @sql1 := CONCAT("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teste_loja (
          id int NOT NULL,
          data date NOT NULL,
          cliente int DEFAULT FALSE,
          id_const int DEFAULT FALSE
        ) ENGINE = innoDB");

          PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql1;
          EXECUTE stmt2;
          DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;


        LEAVE main;
    END IF;



END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Você precisa rodar a procedure que cria o banco novo, conectar-se a ele, criar a procedure que cria as tabelas no banco novo e rodar essa procedure de lá.

Comment: Qual é o seu front-end?

Comment: tente usar o seu `USE `var_banco`$$` dentro do `SET @sql1 := CONCAT(" USE `var_banco`$$ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teste_loja (` ...........

Comment: Eu estou usando php com o framework codeigniter!, Marconcilio eu tentei colocar o USE dentro do SET mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido. a solução mais simples que encontrei foi essa:

eu criei a tabela passando nome_banco.nome_tabela.

```
SET @sql1 := CONCAT("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ",var_banco,".teste_loja (
          id int NOT NULL,
          data date NOT NULL,
          cliente int DEFAULT FALSE,
          id_const int DEFAULT FALSE
        ) ENGINE = innoDB");
```